# Create an enterprise shared contacts folder and integrate it with other services

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps, office365-restapi

Right now our contacts are heavily messed up and spread all around.

What i thinked to do is to create a central contacts repository using Office 365's Exchange and then move them to other services as well (like Mailchimp, SugarCRM and so on) so that everything is in one place (Exchange) and updates can be made from MS Outlook or any email client that supports it.

I checked this guide: https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/office-365-tips/create-a-company-shared-contacts-folder-in-office-365

However i don't know if the APIs can access a folder created like that.

Plus, should i use a database as cache or i should do everything with a script?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access public folders in o365 exchange folders. Exchange Web Services API in o365 contains endpoint for accessing public folders and it provides the ability to add/update or delete properties of exchange folders.

Also, Once you access a public folder, you should be able to use UpdateItem to add or appends properties to selected public folder.

EWS API endpoint:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945067(v=exchg.150).aspx

UpdateItem operation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa581084(v=exchg.150).aspx

Hope this helps.